# IO Exception Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' Error when using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: json.net, mstest, portable-class-library

I've created a Portable Class Library, using the nuget packages for JSON.NET and the Async package

when I try and serialize a class within the portable library I get this error, in my unit test project

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I only seem to get it when there is an public async method on the class. 
Also if I recreate the class within in the test project then it works fine. 
The error only occurs when calling into the portable library (to serialize a class with an async method)

Comment: found a solution here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx

it seems i need to manually edit the app config as nuget isn't doing this correctly for different frameworks.

the two solutions i found worked were either to change the version number to 4.0.0.0 for example.  or just to comment it out entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to remove any binding redirects from your app.config for assemblies installed as part of the Microsoft.Bcl or Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet packages.  The Microsoft.Bcl.Build package will add the correct binding redirects at compile time.